# How to capitalize appendix in ReVTeX?

Tags: appendices, revtex

I am using ReVTeX 4.2 for APS.

```
 \documentclass[%
     reprint,
    superscriptaddress,
     amsmath,amssymb,
     aps,
    ]{revtex4-2}
```

When I use `\appendix` I get this

```
\appendix
\section{ blah  }

some text

\section{blah blah }
```

[image: I get]

Instead, I want it to be "APPENDIX A: blah" and "APPENDIX B: blah blah"

i.e., capitalize only the word "appendix" and the letter (A, B, C, etc.) without capitalizing the section itself ("blah" or "blah blah" remain lowercase as they are).

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to add

```
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{APPENDIX}
```

before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: What if I wanted the entire heading to be capitalized, including the "blah blah"?

Comment: @Ben Type in the title in all capitals.

Comment: I meant automatically, without having to type each one in capitals. So that I can easily change it if I want to.

Comment: @Ben You surely have not so many sections in the appendix, so you can do `\newcommand{\appsection}[1]{\section{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}` and use `\appsection{blah}` in the appendix. If you change your mind, just modify the definition of `\appsection`. Going into the internals of `revtex4` for this seems too much.